# Presence true using validate_timeliness gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any built in method required using validate_timeliness? I want my birthday field to be required, when I separated the presence(like this)

**Model**

```
# validates :birthday, 
    #   :presence => true,
    #   :on => :create
```

it will show both errors(first error will be birthday can't be blank and the other one is birthday is not a valid date).

**Model**

```
validates_date :birthday, :if :birthday,
                              :before => lambda { 18.years.ago },
                              :before_message => "must be at least 18 years old"
                              :end
```

Question: How can I check if my birthday is not a nil?

Note: I also tried this

**Model**

```
  validates_date :birthday, :if birthday.present?,  # here's the line giving an error
                              :before => lambda { 18.years.ago },
                              :before_message => "must be at least 18 years old",
                              :end
```

but it gives me an error expecting  keyword_end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have two different validations:

```
validates :birthday, presence: true
validates_date :birthday, 
               allow_blank: true,
               before: lambda { 18.years.ago },
               before_message: 'must be at least 18 years ago'
```

The second validation allows blank values. This prevents having have two error messages if there is no `birthday` at all. The first validation will still ensure that a `birthday` exists.

Comment: Hi sir, is it possible to make a callback insode of before: lambda { validate_age } ? Inside of that function is if birthday.present? && birthday > Date.today - 18.years
        errors.add(:birthday, 'Age must be at least 18 years old')

Comment: Because if the user is not 18 years old and above.. it will give me an error like Birthday must be at least 18 years old, it must be "Age must be at least 18 years old.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the way how Rails builds error messages. There are [tons of workarounds](https://www.google.de/search?q=rails+validation+message+without+attribute+name), but no best practice nor a Rails' way to remove the attribute name. Just pick a workaround that suits your dependencies and the way how you handle and present error messages. Perhaps changing the error message is the easiest: *Birthday `must be at least 18 years ago`*